# is libprotobuf-lite.so file from CentOS7 working in CentOS8 machine?

Tags: protocol-buffers, centos8

I packaged C++ libprotbuf-lite.so from CentOS7 (libprotobuf-lite.so.8.0.0) to my software. Will it work if installed on CentOS 8 machine?

Answer (score 0):

If the application that uses the protobuf library is compiled using default CentOS 8 g++ compiler with option:

```
 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=gnu++98
```

then it works with the protobuf library from/compiled in CentOS7. Otherwise, it has ABI compatibility issue. By default CentOS7 g++ verison does not use C++11 ABI.